# Remove drop down content when no data

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, haml

I have a drop down menu under a bell icon that displays notifications but when there is no data available for it, it displays this on click :

[image: drop]

my haml :

```
%nav.navbar.navbar-default
        .container
            .navbar-brand= link_to "wat", root_path
            - if user_signed_in?
                %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
                    %li.nav-item.btn-group{"data-behavior"=>"notifications"}
                        %a#dropdownMenu1.dropdown-toggle.nav-link{"aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-haspopup" => "true", "data-behavior" => "notifications-link", "data-toggle" => "dropdown", :type => "button"}
                            = fa_icon "bell"

                            %span.notifs{"data-behavior" => "unread-count"} 
                        .dropdown-menu{"aria-labelledby" => "dropdownMenu1", "data-behavior" => "notification-items"}
```

How to remove the little rectangle ?

Comment: I recommend you to **NOT** do this, since some (if not many) of your users will be confused when there's nothing coming up, since they expect something to come up, why not show them a message saying there aren't any notifications at the moment.

Comment: Nice idea @Simplicity

Comment: @Duke Thanks, One must think about User experience, I've seen people click like madmen when something wasn't doing something other websites did do

Comment: @Simplicity Great guys but that wasn't my question...

Comment: It's just advice my friend, If you check the answers you can see that @Duke has answered

Comment: @jmcastel, which controller responds for viewing `notifications`? does it has parents relations?

Answer (score 1):

Check if has data before add `.dropdown-menu` div

```
- if hasData?
  .dropdown-menu{"aria-labelledby" => "dropdownMenu1", "data-behavior" => "notification-items"}
```

Comment: i have this : undefined method `hasData?

Comment: @jmcastel It's just a example, I don't know how you can check if has data to show, if you have `@notifications` you can maybe check if `@notifications.lenght` is greater than one.